# SharePoint List lookup value not adding additional fields values

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a main list 'Actions Types', where to each type of 'Action Type ID' is assigned a Person (using Person of Group field).

Using a JSON code, I created a single text column (named 'Owner Email Address') column where the email address of that person is extracted.

Now I have a second list: Actions.

Each action has an 'Action type' lookup column so that when the type value is selected (from the 'Action Type ID' list)  then the related  'Owner Email Address' is pulled in .

No value is added though, the field remains blank. If I add default additional fields such as 'Modified' or 'Created' those appears correctly.

Has anybody some clue while the 'Owner Email Address' values , which is a single text column, are not being pulled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first JSON you are using to show the email address in 'Owner Email Address' field is written using SharePoint JSON formatting and SharePoint JSON formatting only customizes the **display** of columns/views. It does not store/save any value in the column the itself.

Hence, you cannot refer the "displayed" values of 'Owner Email Address' column using the SharePoint lookup column in the second SharePoint list (Actions).

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

[image]

You will have to store the actual email addresses in 'Owner Email Address' column using Power Apps customized forms or using Power automate flow (on item creation and/or item update).